# How to decrement a font-size percentage with .css()

Tags: jquery

I have a jsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/pbkt3nrx/1/ - where I want to decrease the font-size of the html element by 5% each time the "Shrink" button is clicked. But the first click reduces the font-size from 62.5% (10px) to 5px. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

```
$(function(){   
    $('button#shrink').mousedown(function() {
            $('html').css('font-size', '-=5%');
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is also correct.your current size is 10 px and you are reducing by 5 px.so this is reason it disappears after 2nd click.

Try this:by reducing size by 1px

```
$(function(){   
    $('button#shrink').mousedown(function() {
        curSize= parseInt($('html').css('font-size')) -1; 
        //here parseInt will remove px from 10px ,final value would be only 10
        $('html').css('font-size', curSize);
                       });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pbkt3nrx/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){   
    $('button#shrink').mousedown(function() {
            font = parseInt($("html").css("font-size"));   //Get current font-size
            font = font-1;  //Decrease font-size by 1
            $('html').css('font-size', font);  //Apply new font-size to current font-size
        });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbkt3nrx/3/)**

Comment: what is the difference between your and my answer dude?

Comment: @Mr7-itsurdeveloper Proper format with explaination

Comment: Both these answers reduce the font-size by 1px. That's actually easy to do with $('html').css('font-size', '-=1px');  I want to keep the units % and decrease it by 5% each click.

Comment: @Steve my answer works on firefox, i am not sure why it does not in chrome, check it out, it will need just an easy fix i guess, have no time for that

Comment: @Steve now it does :)

Answer (score 0):

this should work http://jsfiddle.net/pbkt3nrx/5/

```
$(function () {
var shrinks = 0;
$('button#shrink').mousedown(function () {
    var currentHeight = $('html').css('font-size');
    currentHeight = currentHeight.substring(0,currentHeight.length-2);
    shrinks++;
    console.log(currentHeight);
    $('html').css('font-size', +62.5-5*shrinks + '%');
});
});
```